# Preventing out of office storms Exchange 2010, OWA and Auto Forward to a group

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-web-app, mail-forwarding, email

In my organization we have a group mailbox for a particular function.  The actual function is preformed by 15 - 20 individuals on a rotating basis. The group mailbox serves as a record for all e-mail sent to that function.  Individual access to the mailbox is established by adding a user to an A/D group. For convenience, those members of the group would prefer to not have to "check" this group/non-entiyy mailbox.  To achieve that, I want to forward all incoming mail to the group mailbox to that group. So far I am not seeing any consistency in the way an out of office response looks in order to build an exception to the forward rule. We have not turned this feature on for the group, instead waiting until we are sure this will not be an issue.

**How do I preventing out of office replies to the group mailbox from being forwarded to the group?**

Management of the mailbox is conducted via OWA.
Exchange 2010

Answer (score 1):

First it sounds like you want a distribution list not a mailbox that then forwards it's email to the group.  As for the out of office messages, they only go to the person sending the email not everyone who is cc'ed on the email.